# Jenkins Slaves cannot connect to the Master Jenkins

Tags: windows, jenkins, https

I switched the `Jenkins` to using `https` on port `8080` . After a restart of the `Jenkins`,the slaves cannot reconnect.

I changed only `Jenkins` location from Configure System -> Jenkins Location -> Jenkins `URL` to https://localhost:8080

Comment: Are these JLNP slaves?

Comment: Your Jenkins Slaves (JNLP) should connect over a different port. Check your Jenkins configuration (manage Jenkins > Global Security > agents)

Comment: @RavindranathBarathy they are JLNP slaves .

@ansib on which port they should connect to Jenkins . Currently it`s 46551 ?

Comment: @SvetoslavAngelov if they are configured to run over jnlp you should check your configuration at the agent side. you could read how at this documentation https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds under "agent to master connections". Could you also check and share your configuration under "manage jenkins > manage nodes"? Are there some agents listed?